# Let the [flame]s burn?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

It seems that the [flame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flame) tag has no guidance, no wiki and 2 followers.

It has 13 questions (as of writing), that, as far as I could gather, refer to a wide range of different things, including:

- The Fractal Flame Algorithm ([described here](http://flam3.com/flame.pdf))
- Creating or drawing animated fire and flames
- Very specific things (temperature equation of a flame, fire alarm sensors on Arduino, etc)

I'd like to know your opinion about it; where I'm standing, it seems very ambiguous and misleading.

I'd propose its elimination. It is possible create a [fractal-flame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fractal-flame) tag, if necessary (I'm not sure if it qualifies). The other uses seem unnecessary.

What do you think?

Comment: I'm not sure you need to go through the burnination process for a tag with only 13 questions, especially if it has no tag wiki.

Comment: @TylerH I'm pretty sure it was for the pun. Not that I disapprove.

Comment: Looks like someone has already started burning it, down to 5 questions now

Comment: I removed the more obvious ones, but I left the flame fractal related; should we rename the tag? I can create a flame-fractal, add a bit of a wiki and retag the remaining five. Or is it just the fractal tag enough?

Comment: I've removed another, it was actually a Lua question, the fractal angle was only really incidental. Of the four remaining, two are duplicates of each other (the same question asked twice by the same user), so that's three actual questions. IMO [tag:fractal] is specific enough, and there is no need for [tag:fractal-flame].

Answer (score 6):

**Update:**

The [flame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flame) tag now exists once more, but it is used to refer to the Flutter game engine, [Flame](https://github.com/flame-engine/flame). This is a proper use of the tag in the context of Stack Overflow, and it should be retained. All questions that have this tag are using it properly, and I don't really see a need to disambiguate it at this time.

If disambiguation becomes necessary, I would suggest perhaps [flame-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flame-engine). Feel free to leave a comment below if you know something about this technology and would prefer a different name. Also, feel free to ping me if this tag starts getting misused for things other than the Flutter game engine, which would argue for a rename to help avoid ambiguity.

Comment: I think `flame` is perfectly clear to refer to the game engine, and I agree no ambiguity remains.

Comment: Isn't the normal naming scheme "[language-feature]"? E.g. [flutter-flame]? Instead of [flame-engine].

Answer (score 1):

I agree that [flame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flame) reads the wrong way on the first sight, because we're on the Internet.

I would try to split graphics-related and physics-related tags for flame, e.g. [flame-graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flame-graphics) and [burning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burning), or something. Input from people from physics.SE, or some research, is needed to decide upon the right tag, or maybe even use an existing closely related tag.

Comment: Upvoted not for agreement, but so that the community user will stop bumping this question.

Comment: Upvoting again for the same reason, since it got bumped again.